# what's the meaning of plotcp result in rpart?

Tags: r, rpart

Someone know what that means of horizontal line means?I got the explanation in R:

```
minline:whether a horizontal line is drawn 1SE above the minimum of the curve.
```

What's 1SE??

Answer (score 1):

The line drawn by the plotcp represents the highest cross-validated error less than the minimum cross-validated error plus the standard deviation of the error at that tree.

Check out this: 
http://scg.sdsu.edu/ctrees_r/